# ESBuilld Could not resolve package error when building from Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, yarn-workspaces, esbuild, yarn-v2

I'm trying to create a docker image that would compile and run an application from my monorepo. I'm using ESBuild to bundle and compile all the dependencies in a single file, this process works fine when I run the bundle command manually but it fails when it's ran by Docker.

The reported error is about the other workspaces the application depends on, this is an example:

```
#10 1.443 ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@platform/bar"
#10 1.443 
#10 1.443     src/app/logger.ts:1:29:
#10 1.443       1 │ import { createBar } from '@platform/bar'
#10 1.443         ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#10 1.443 
#10 1.443   You can mark the path "@platform/bar" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn workspace @platform/foo bundle

WORKDIR /platform/packages/apps/foo/dist

EXPOSE 8181

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "@platform/foo",
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "node bundle.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@platform/bar": "workspace:*",
    "@platform/xyz": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

**bundle.mjs**

```js
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild'
import { copy } from 'esbuild-plugin-copy'

await esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['src/main.ts'],
  bundle: true,
  outfile: 'dist/app.js',
  plugins: [
    copy({
      resolveFrom: 'cwd',
      verbose: true,
      assets: [
        {
          from: ['../../../node_modules/couchbase/build/**/*.node'],
          to: ['./dist'],
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  platform: 'node',
  target: 'node18',
  loader: {
    '.node': 'copy',
  },
})
```